# Número menor primos en una matriz 3*3

Tags: java

No he podido aplicar el algoritmo para obtener el número menor primos en una matriz 3*3 en Java.

```
public void numprimos(int matriz[][]) {
    int cnp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
             if (matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                cnp++;
                System.out.println("numero primo =" + matriz[i][j]);
                System.out.println("La cantidad de numeros primos es :" + cnp + "y su posicion es :"+i+"-"+j);
```

Comment: ¿Podrias explicar mejor que intentas hacer exactamente?

Comment: Me parece que lo primero que debes pensar es como determinar si un número es primo, que lo estás haciendo mal. Los número primos son aquellos que solo son divisibles entre ellos mismos y entre 1.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿y el resto del código?

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a dejar un pequeño programa que acabo de crear en el cual nos averigua en una matriz de números, qué números son Primos, indicándonos su posición dentro de la misma, los números primos totales de esa matriz, y el número primo mas bajo o menor de ella.

```
/**
 * Un número primo es aquel número que solo es divisible por si mismo y por la unidad.
 * @author Diego L. Ortiz Lopez
 */
public class EsPrimoTest2 {
    public static int[][] laMatriz = {{71,4,99},{6,3,29},{18,4,112},{23,44,412},{63,617,2},{28,103,124}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        esPrimoMenor(laMatriz);
    }

    public static void esPrimoMenor(int[][] matriz){
        int aux = 0;
        int menor = 0;
        int contPrim = 0;
        boolean esMenor = true;
        for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                //System.out.print(matriz[x][y] + "\t");
                if(esPrimo(matriz[x][y])){
                    contPrim++;
                    aux = matriz[x][y]; 
                    System.out.print("\"Primo: "+matriz[x][y] + " y su posición es: "+x+"-"+y+"\"\n");
                    if(aux < menor || esMenor){
                        menor = aux;
                        esMenor = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("La cantidad de números primos es: " + contPrim);
        System.out.println("Numero menor primo: "+menor);
    }

    public static boolean esPrimo(int num){
        int contador = 2;
        boolean primo = true;
        while((primo) && (contador != num)){
            if(num % contador == 0)
                primo = false;
            contador++;
        }
        return primo;
    } 


}
```

---

Si alguien quiere aportar o como optimizar el código, o ve algún error, pues es bienvenido. Saludos!!

P.d. Este código vale para cualquier matriz o debería valer. :)